# return correct data to mvc View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to populate data in a view from an sql db. Im selecting all recipes from a specific counry...O.k...I also want to display the country name at the top of the view but im having problems returning the result to the view. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...

Heres my code

```
 @model IEnumerable<FoodB.recipeTbl>

 <h2>************where i want to put the country title***************88</h2>
 <table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.recipe_title)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ingredients)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.country_id)
    </th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.recipe_title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ingredients)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.country_id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
    </td>
</tr>
 }

 </table>
```

Here's my controller

```
  public ActionResult Index(int id)
    { 
        //select all recipes for country          
        var query = db.recipeTbls.Where(c => c.country_id == id);

        //get country from country table*******how to return this***********
        var ctry = db.countryTbls.Where(country => country.id == id);

        return View(query);

    }
```

Comment: for just showing the country name I would pass the name through the viewbag

Comment: Hey!...Tried that. getting error...SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id], [Extent1].[recipe_title] AS [recipe_title], [Extent1].[ingredients] AS [ingredients], [Extent1].[country_id] AS [country_id] FROM [dbo].[recipeTbl] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[country_id] = @p__linq__0 ,,,,when i execute                                                  var ctry = db.countryTbls.Where(country => country.id == id);
ViewBag.country = ctry.ToString();//return country via view bag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Where` since you are looking for one entry only

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
    { 
        //select all recipes for country          
        var query = db.recipeTbls.SingleOrDefault(c => c.country_id == id);

        //get country from country table*******how to return this***********
        var ctry = db.countryTbls.SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
        ViewBag.Country = ctry;

        return View(query);

    }
```

**View**

```
<h1>ViewBag.Country </h1>
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for reply.Now i get the error System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.countryTbl_B0E08AAE9DC0BB3D52F84075A0E8FB0D1... in my database the column country holds a string so the query c => c.country == id(int) gives me an error cannot be applied to operators of type string and int???

Comment: Oops. sorry I mistyped. Change it to `c.country.id == id`

Comment: Man im pulling my hair out:)...now im getting an error: string does not contain a definition for 'id'??? what is c.country.id in reference to??? is this the same as 'select country from countryTbl where id == id'???

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry. I haven't had sleep. I edited my answer.

Comment: IT should be c.id == id

Comment: The solution was ViewBag.Country = ctry.Country

Comment: You did not show your model, so I didn't know that there was a `Country` property for `ctry`.

Answer (score 1):

viewbag is a field that is dynamic.  you can set it to whatever type you want.  So on your controller

```
ViewBag.Country = ctry;
```

then in your view

```
<label>@ViewBag.Country</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ViewBag.

The controller

```
  public ActionResult Index(int id)
    { 
        //select all recipes for country          
        var query = db.recipeTbls.Where(c => c.country_id == id);

        //get country from country table*******how to return this***********
        var ctry = db.countryTbls.Where(country => country.id == id);
        ViewBag.country = ctry.ToString();
        return View(query);
    }
```

The view

```
@model IEnumerable<FoodB.recipeTbl>

 <h2>ViewBag.country</h2>
```

Hope it worked.